# How to parse media:content in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xml

How to parse media:content (xml tag) in swift using standard XMLParser?
I have this code

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
   currentElement = elementName
   if currentElement == "item" {
      for key in elements.keys {
         elements[key] = ""
      }
   }
}
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
   let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
   if tagName == currentElement {
      elements[tagName]! += trimmedString
   }
}
```

which works fine for this kind of tag

```
<guid> url </guid>
```

and as well as title, description tags, but doesn't work for this one

```
<media:content width="width" url="url">
     <media:credit scheme="scheme"> Text
     </media:credit>
</media:content>
```

I am trying to parse this xml https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide a [example] showing what you already tried and what part is not working.

Comment: @koen Thank you for feedback. Edited the question.

Comment: The part `width="width" url="url"` is called the attributeDict. So for instance to extract the url, you do `url = attributeDict["url"]`.